# WPF: When do I need to call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I know that `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` is needed whenever I'm updating the GUI on a background thread. But how do I determine at runtime if it is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [Dispatcher.CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.checkaccess.aspx).

Comment: Grr. I hate it when they hide useful functions from the Intillisense.